# Break line not executing

Tags: python

```
while True:
password = input('Enter your password')
passwordlist = list(password)
upper=False
lower=False
for letters in passwordlist:
    if letters == letters.upper():
        upper = True
    if letters == letters.lower():
        lower = True
    if len(password) <=5:
        print('password is to short')
    elif Name in password or Surname in password:
        print('You cannot have first or last name in password')
    elif upper == False or lower == False:
        print('You must have both upper and lower case in password')
    elif upper == True and lower == True:
        print('Password is valid')
    break
```

When I run my code it is able to see if I use my first and last name, but it is not able to determine if I have used both upper and lower case as if my password contains both it returns me with `You must have both upper and lower case in password` even though I have used both

So my question is why my code is not able to detect both upper and lower case letters in password.
Why does my `break` line not execute

Comment: your break line executes at first iteration, unless you have a formatting problem in your question.

Comment: `upper == True and lower == True` cannot happen. You should check `isupper` & `islower` function.

Comment: You definitely have formatting issues in the code you posted. Please check the indentation and correct any mistakes.

Comment: Jean Francois Could you show me how?

Comment: I have tried indenting does not work?

Comment: Since your question was marked as duplicated I answered it in here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39991064/in-python-how-do-you-check-if-a-string-has-both-uppercase-and-lowercase-letters/47601526#47601526
Check the isupper and islower that @Jean-François Fabre wrote about.